# Why do my web api receive null values when posting to web API?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My Web API is receiving null value in `Httpclient PostAsJsonAsync`:

```
public static async Task<DefaultApiResponse<T>> PostList<T>(string url, string token, List<AddEventViewModel.Agenda> request)
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);

        var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);

        var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
        var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
        byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        var httpResponse = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, byteContent);

        var defaultresponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DefaultApiResponse<T>>(await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

        return defaultresponse;
    }
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

I would try posting as a StringContent object instead

```
var content = new StringContent(
                     JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request),
                     Encoding.UTF8,
                     "application/json");

defaultresponse = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
```

Comment: it's still postting null values if I use the postAsync method. But if i use the postjsonAsync method is sends data with all the content type headers and eveything but the list object is null

Comment: Is your serialization working before you send? and how is your Agenda-class constructed?

Comment: yes I debug my code and it serialized my list of object to json data but when it used postAsync method it only sends a null value

Comment: i just constructed Agenda class as a list and I define the properties of that list in the same class file.

Comment: And you also tried sending without converting it to a bytearray?

Comment: yes I also tried it but unfortunately it still sends a null value to the api

Comment: It seems like (in my simple research) that the PostAsJsonAsync()-method do serialize the input. You could try posting with your 'request'-object unmodified.

Comment: the data being sent it still null even though i'm now using the PostAsJsonAsync() method.

Comment: @christianibana Try extending your original question with information on what you have tried so far, and what is being sent and received on the other end. Maybe someone else knows the answer :)